# Nvidia CUDA Profiler's timeline contains many large gaps

Tags: cuda, nvidia, profile, timeline

I'm trying to profile my code using Nivida Profiler, but I'm getting strange gaps in the timeline as shown below:

[image: Timeline Gaps]

Note: both kernels on the edges of the gaps are CudaMemCpyAsync (Host-to-Device)

I'm running on Ubuntu 14.04 with latest version of CUDA, 8.0.61 and latest Nvidia display driver.

Intel integrated graphics card is used in display not Nvidia. So, Nvidia Graphics card is only running the code, not anything else.

I've enabled CPU Profiling as well to check these gaps but nothing is shown!

[image: Cpu Profiling is enabled]

Also, no Debugging options are enabled (-G nor -g)
and this is a "release build"

[image: No Debugging options are enabled]

My laptop's specs:

- Intel Core i7 4720HQ
- Nvidia GTX 960m
- 16GB DDR3 Ram
- 1 TB Hard Drive

Is there anyway to trace what's happening in these empty time slots?

Thanks,

Comment: Those large gaps are about 0.1 ms ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid there are no automatic methods, but you can add custom traces in your code to find what's happening :

To do that you can use NVTX.

follow the links for some [tutorials](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cuda-pro-tip-generate-custom-application-profile-timelines-nvtx/) or [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#nvtx).

These profiling holes are probably due to data loading, memory allocations/initialisations done by the host between your kernels executions.

Comment: I'll try that and post my feedback. Thanks

Comment: Well, it worked. These gaps were actually CPU codes that I wrote to read input data from hard disk but I didn't know they are taking this long time. Thanks :)